# passing Data from an Array in lineChart React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, render

i have to show a LineChart in my React Native app, which will take data from Firebase, the data point is being read as a number,

```
 <LineChart
    data=

    {{
      // labels: ["January", "February"],
      datasets: 
      [
        {
          data: [10,5]//this.state.myArray.values
        }



      ]

    }}
```

If i show the manual [10,5], the line comes, but it doesn't read myArray that have values that i am reading from firebase. 
 This part is written in my CompoundWillMount function.

```
var ZERO_ = this.state.myArray.concat(0);
this.setState({ myArray: ZERO_ })

var joined = this.state.myArray.concat(this.state.speedVolts);


this.setState({ myArray: joined })

//this.setState({ myArray: this.state.myArray.concat(this.state.speedVolts) })
console.log(this.state.myArray)
```

can anyone help please?